# Send mail with Pentaho through Microsoft Exchange Server

Tags: smtp, exchange-server, pentaho

We recently migrated our company e-mails to Microsoft Exchange-Server, and we had many automations that used the old server address and ports, plus not using SSL/TLS.

So when we migrated, the server configurations were no longer valid for the e-mails, and we didn't have any source material on how to properly connect to Exchange-Server to automate mails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/office365-smtp-configuration-receives-authentication-errors-646250764.html) documentation on the web, of a similar stack-trace to mine, that had the SMTP Server and ports for configuration.

[image]

Using these configurations i was able to succesfully send automated mails through PDI normally like before.

This was done using PDI 7.0.0.0-25